# Can't send mail to certain address like iccloud.com or faswebnet.it

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, plesk

as described in title i can't send mails to iccloud.com or faswebnet.it. Mails reamins in queque on postfix and never sent.

On postfix log i have:

```
Jun 15 20:18:05 server postfix/smtp[5637]: connect to iccloud.com[47.90.50.105]:25: Connection timed out
Jun 15 20:18:06 server postfix/smtp[5637]: 9CFAF408007A: to=<lampis.silvia@iccloud.com>, relay=none, delay=30, delays=0.13/0/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to iccloud.com[47.90.50.105]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Also i have some warnins like

```
Jun 15 20:17:35 server postfix/smtpd[5626]: warning: hostname server.ordinepsicologiabruzzo.it does not resolve to address 149.202.68.157
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your log messages are generated by two different events.  What  is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that your connection is timing out. In most cases, then next thing that I would try is to determine why the connection is timing out by perhaps trying a ping and/or traceroute test. Then, because sometimes those are blocked, I might try to use netcat or maybe telnet to connect to port 25 to try to manually make the mail connection to see what is happening.

However, in this case, I don't think that's what's happening. Even my own connection cannot connect to that IP:

```
$ ping -c3 iccloud.com
PING domain.88u.com (47.90.50.105) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- domain.88u.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2069ms
```

When using `nc`, it times out to port 25, too, meaning that it's not just your location that can't connect.

But the important bit is that I don't think mail connections *should* be going there. Here's a dig result showing the MX entry:

```
$ dig +short iccloud.com MX
domain.88u.com.
```

This means that your server shouldn't be connecting to iccloud.com to send email for @iccloud.com addresses, but to domain.88u.com.

I would recommend doing a similar dig, or maybe even try:

```
dig +trace iccloud.com MX
```

The next step seems to be trying to figure out why your server isn't using the proper host for that domain's email.

Currently, faswebnet.it doesn't seem to have any public MX record.